# Which Hindu book talks about how women behave compared to men?

Tags: women

I'm looking for any book from the Hindu tradition that explains how and why women differ in their natural behaviour from that of men. I'm not talking about what is forbidden to women, nor about how their biology differs. I'm looking for an ancient version of woman's psychology book, such as "men are from mars and women are from venus" by John Gray.